# String prefix and Suffix separated by ": " in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, prefix, suffix

In Swift I want to extract the Prefix until space and Suffix until space both separated by ": ". If white space between strings it should be next line.
Ex:

```
Apple: Fruit Tomato: Vegetable Iron: Material
```

Result needed as

```
Apple: Fruit
Tomato: Vegetable
Iron: Material
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression `"(?<!:) "` to replace the white spaces `" "` occurrences where it is not preceded by colon punctuation `":"`:

```
let string = "Apple: Fruit Tomato: Vegetable Iron: Material"
let pattern = "(?<!:) "
let result = string.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "\n", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)    // "Apple: Fruit\nTomato: Vegetable\nIron: Material\n"
```